# Send an e-mail with attachment with angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, email

I'm using `$window.open()` to send an e-mail to a specific destination, but I can't send it with an attachment or embedded image.

I have something like this:

```
$window.open('mailto:xxx@xxx.xx?subject=Subject&body=Body&attachment=http://images0.minutemediacdn.com/production/912x516/57ea81dce8f2a0c893000001.jpg');
```

Is there any away to solve this and send an e-mail with that picture (embedded or attach)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't send an email directly with javascript. You can only open the user's mail client:

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com');
```

There are also some parameters to pre-fill the subject and the body:

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');
```

Comment: My question is how to pre-fill the attachment.

Comment: Sorry you can't . There is no attachment parameter to pre-fill.

Comment: And embedded a picture (using url) in email body?

Comment: No. If you have been familiar with javascript, why don't you try out nodejs. It is framework for javascript. Check out this tutorial http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/07/02/send-email-node-js-express/